# Bash variables with space (directories)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, bash-scripting

I'm trying to echo all of the files in `/foo` while preserving the spaces within listed directories. Currently, a directory titled `"bar1 bar2"` will echo out as `/path/to/foo/bar1/` then `/bar2` then `file.txt` all on new lines. I need it to echo `/path/to/foo/bar1 bar2/file.txt` or `/path/to/foo/bar1\ bar2/file.txt`.

```
for file in $(find /path/to/foo/ -type f); do
  if [[ ... ]]; then
    echo "${file}"
  fi
done
```

Also tried:

```
for file in $(find /path/to/foo/ -type f | sed 's/ /\ /g'); do
  if [[ ... ]]; then
    echo "${file}"
    echo "$file" # variations i've tried
    echo $file   # variations i've tried
    echo ${file}
    otherCommand "${file}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Here's a rule for Linux Life: If you have trouble doing it in Bash, *stop doing it in Bash* and use something else.... Bash is a terrible language. Use Perl or something.

Comment: Also see: https://superuser.com/a/117600/334516

Comment: Also see:   [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/80216)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not with `$file`, it's with your usage of `$(find…)`.

Both regular variables and `$(…)` process substitutions are subject to exactly the same kind of word-splitting. If you put `$(find…)` in double quotes, you get a *single* word with all output. If you don't, it will be split up at any whitespace – *not* just newlines or some other magical boundary that you probably expected.

An important part of the above is that backslash escapes are *not* processed when expanding the variable. It's just split at spaces and that's it.

(In other words, quoting `$file` didn't help because it never had the correct value in the first place!)

If you want to process all files recursively, your options are:

1. Read output from `find` in another way:

   ```
   find … -print | while read -r file; do
       echo "Got $file"
   done
   ```

   (Side note: File names may *technically* include newlines as well, so you might want to guard against that, as rare as it is:

   ```
   find … -print0 | while read -r -d "" file; do
       echo "Got $file"
   done
   ```
2. For small amounts of files, use bash's extended wildcards:

   ```
   shopt -s globstar
   for file in /path/to/foo/**; do
       echo "Got $file"
   done
   ```

With large directories, the advantage of `find | while read` is that it's streamed – your script will process results as they come. Meanwhile, both `$(find)` and wildcards have to collect *everything* into memory first, and only then return the (possibly massive) results.

On the other hand, using a pipe affects the *entire* `while` loop (not just the `read` command), so if you want to run *anything* that wants to read keyboard input, you have to manually provide it with the original stdin, e.g. `vim "$file" < /dev/tty`.

Comment: Wow; your response time was incredible. Thank you so much.

Comment: @super-frustrated Then you should mark it "accepted"

Comment: Apologies. I don't use stackexchanges often. Marked it.

Comment: It's best to use `... | IFS= read ...`; without that, `read` will remove leading and trailing whitespace (which is rare, but perfectly legal in filenames). Also, note that the pipe makes the loop run in s subshell, so any variables set in it will not be available outside the loop. See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for more tips and tricks.

Comment: Newlines aren't that rare. I definitely know better, but I still accidentally ended up with some by copying text from a webpage and pasting it into a file name. What you see is definitely not always what you get! I have not yet seen a file name with leading or trailing spaces in it. That could take quite awhile to debug if the variables aren't properly defended. It's almost totally invisible.

Comment: Leading spaces should be fairly obvious if you do `ls` or `find -print`.